# REST API (thingiverse) using ruby

Tags: ruby, rest

I am a first stepper on Ruby. (and REST APIs) Makerbot 3D printer user community thingiverse is providing REST API to download .stl files. I am making simple ruby plugin for Google sketchup to bring downloaded file to the scene.

How does  API works on ruby?
Is following simple code supposed to be?

```
 require 'net/http'
 url = URI.parse('http://www.thingiverse.com/thing/199900')
 resp = http.request(url).body
```

Anybody can explain(or introduce reference) how REST API on Ruby works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample, you're not really using REST, or are only using GET from REST.

The simplest URI to HTTP request library for Ruby is built-into the language: [Open::URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html), and can do this easily:

```
require 'open-uri'
body = open('http://www.thingiverse.com/thing/199900').read
```

You can do it using Net::HTTP, which is also built-in, or other external-to-Ruby gems, but Open::URI is there and will handle this request simply. Net::HTTP is underneath Open::URI and will require a lot more code for a reasonably robust interface.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to this [Thingiverse API Ruby Gem](https://github.com/makerbot/thingiverse-ruby).

Or consider writing your on API wrapper with Ruby: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/writing-an-api-wrapper-in-ruby-with-tdd/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [REST Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem.